# Separate individual pdf pages from 2x2 format to 1x1 format

Tags: pdf

My teacher gives us his lectures as a PDF file with a 2 by 2 format. I.e. on one pdf page, there are 4 slides of the presentation (see sketch below).

Does anyone know how to separate each individual pdf page of a multi-page pdf document into 4 pages? I am not looking for coding advice, but rather for a tool that does this for me.

The current page format is like this:

```
    +-----------+
    |  1  |  2  |
    -------------
    |  3  |  4  |
    +-----------+
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Adobe Acrobat as a liquid option. You could use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of free time, you could take a screenshot of every slide(snip tool) or convert the PDF to word or power point, apply your changes and then convert it back. As far as i know, no function in PDF does what you have asked directly.